# Why is my form authentication helper method causing the entire submit input type to be wiped from the page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I wrote a helper method that will output the HTML to authenticate a form:

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def auth_token
    "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"authenticity_token\" value=\"#{form_authenticity_token}\"".html_safe
  end
end
```

And I tried using it in this portion of my HTML code in the application.html.erb:

```
<% if logged_in? %>
    <p>Logged In</p>
    <form action="<%= session_url %>" method="POST">
      <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE">
      <%= auth_token %>
      <input type="submit" value="Logout">
    </form>
  <% else %>
    <p>Logged out</p>
    <form action="<%= new_session_url %>" method="GET">
      <input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="<%= form_authenticity_token %>">
      <input type="submit" value="Login">
    </form> 
  <% end %>
```

I'm testing one button at a time, so only the logout button is using this helper method at the moment! However, once I log in, the logout button doesn't show (but the paragraph text does appear). And when I type out the form authentication input tag explicitly instead of using my helper method, it works. I double checked my helper method and erb tags, and it looks correct to me. Any ideas on why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

`>` is missing in your helper method, add `>` at the end of string.

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def auth_token
    "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"authenticity_token\" value=\"#{form_authenticity_token}\">".html_safe
  end
end
```

Comment: AH! Thank you so much, my eyes need a break! Also, I came across another way to write this html. Could I do something like: content_tag(:ul, :input, hidden, :name, authenticity_token, :value, form_authenticity_token)?

Comment: i would recommend using `hidden_field_tag('authenticity_token', form_authenticity_token)`

Answer (score 0):

You can just use [`form_tag`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-form_tag) (Rails 4):

```
<%= form_tag(session_url) do %>
  # ...
<% end %>
```

Or [`form_with`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2.3/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-form_with) (Rails 5+):

```
<%= form_with(url: session_url, method: :post) do |f| %>
  # ...
<% end %>
```

Both will render the `authenticity_token` input for you.

Comment: Oh wow! That's really helpful to know, thank you! And is it possible to do the standard attribute notation (with the = and "") or do these both require that the attributes be listed as symbols? And out of curiosity, is there another way to write what I had using content_tag?

Comment: "is it possible to do the standard attribute notation (with the = and "")" No - these are hash arguments to a method. `method: 'POST'` and `method: :post` give the exact same results though.

Comment: Since `<input>` doesn't have content you would use `tag` instead of `content_tag`. But you can also just use `hidden_field_tag(:authenticity_token, form_authenticity_token)` as that would be really verbose.

Comment: Ahh ok, so from what I understand, the `hidden_field_tag(:authenticity_token, form_authenticity_token)` takes care of the input tag as well?

Comment: The question makes no sense. `hidden_field_tag` returns `<input type="hidden" ...>`.

Comment: Sorry, what I meant was that if I were to use `hidden_field_tag(:authenticity_token, form_authenticity_token)`, then would that be the only line of code that I need to put into the helper method? Or do I need to mention the input tag anywhere else in that helper method?

Comment: Actually I just looked at the API for it and it makes sense now! Thanks!